# How can I create a local database inside a Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Express project?

Tags: c++, database, visual-c++, sqlite

How can I create a local database inside a Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Express project?

I can't find this simple answer in the web. The only answer I've found is for Visual Studio: using project > add new item > local database. But this option isn't available in Visual c++ 2010 Express edition.

I tried installing "Microsoft SQL Server Compact 4" and "Microsoft SQL Server Denali", and updating "Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Express" from "Windows Update".

Comment: MSVC used to have dbase projects.  All removed around VS2008, just about nobody writes dbase code in C++.  Not a lot of users noticed, IDE support was always lacking anyway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, I got a solution at last. Regrettably I must answer my own question...

I used SQLite library (http://www.sqlite.org/). It was a little complicated because the sqlite documentation is a bit vague, but I did as follows:

> - Download sqlitedll*.zip - extract .def and .dll files somewhere.
> - Generate the lib file with a command like "c:\program
>     files\micros~1\vc98\bin\lib" /def:sqlite3.def". Do that from a command
>     prompt, in the directory with the .def file in, with the appropriate
>     path to your lib.exe. You may need to run vcvars32.bat first, which is
>     also in the bin directory. Copy the resulting .lib to an appropriate
>     place, and set that as a library directory in VC++. (Or do it on a
>     per-project basis.)
> - Download the sqlite-source*.zip file, and extract the sqlite3.h file
>     from within to a suitable directory. Set that as an include directory
>     in VC++. (Again, you could do it on a per-project basis.)
> - In your project, #include  as required, add sqlite3.lib
>     to your project, copy the sqlite3.dll to your executable's directory
>     or working directory, and you should be ready to go.

Then, is easy to use no-out queries, but if you want to use a SQL "SELECT" for example, you could use this code:

```
std::string queries;
// A prepered statement for fetching tables
sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
// Create a handle for database connection, create a pointer to sqlite3
sqlite3 *handle;
// try to create the database. If it doesnt exist, it would be created
// pass a pointer to the pointer to sqlite3, in short sqlite3**
int retval = sqlite3_open("local.db",&handle);
// If connection failed, handle returns NULL
if(retval){
    System::Windows::Forms::MessageBox::Show("Database connection failed");
    return;
}       
// Create the SQL query for creating a table
char create_table[100] = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (uname TEXT PRIMARY KEY,pass TEXT NOT NULL,activated INTEGER)";
// Execute the query for creating the table
retval = sqlite3_exec(handle,create_table,0,0,0);
// Insert first row and second row
queries = "INSERT INTO users VALUES('manish','manish',1)";
retval = sqlite3_exec(handle,queries.c_str(),0,0,0);
queries = "INSERT INTO users VALUES('mehul','pulsar',0)";
retval = sqlite3_exec(handle,queries.c_str(),0,0,0);
// select those rows from the table
queries = "SELECT * from users";
retval = sqlite3_prepare_v2(handle,queries.c_str(),-1,&stmt,0);
if(retval){
    System::Windows::Forms::MessageBox::Show("Selecting data from DB Failed");
    return ;
}
// Read the number of rows fetched
int cols = sqlite3_column_count(stmt);
while(1){
    // fetch a row’s status
    retval = sqlite3_step(stmt);
    if(retval == SQLITE_ROW){
    // SQLITE_ROW means fetched a row
    // sqlite3_column_text returns a const void* , typecast it to const char*
        for(int col=0 ; col<cols;col++){
            const char *val = (const char*)sqlite3_column_text(stmt,col);
            System::Windows::Forms::MessageBox::Show(stdstr2systemstr(sqlite3_column_name(stmt,col))+" = "+stdstr2systemstr(val));
        }
    }
    else
    if(retval == SQLITE_DONE){
            // All rows finished
            System::Windows::Forms::MessageBox::Show("All rows fetched");
            break;
        }
        else{
            // Some error encountered
            System::Windows::Forms::MessageBox::Show("Some error encountered");
            return ;
        }
    }
    // Close the handle to free memory
    sqlite3_close(handle);
```

I expect this info be useful!

Sources:

- [http://www.gamedev.net/topic/332251-sqlite3-and-visual-c/page_*p*_3157685#entry3157685](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/332251-sqlite3-and-visual-c/page__p__3157685#entry3157685)
- http://milky.manishsinha.net/2009/03/30/sqlite-with-c/